# Why is the space outside the Enterprise blue, not black?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

I've noticed that space on the view screen of the original series Enterprise is blue, not black. In some cases, everything is slightly off-centered to the right.  Why is this? e.g. 5:29 of

Comment: I'm talking about original, not enhanced effects.

Comment: Are you looking for in-universe or out-of-universe?

Answer (score 8):

Space is dark blue instead of black in that part of the video because of video compression effects.  [Lossy compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression) loses color fidelity as well as spatial resolution from the compressed video frames and you're seeing a pretty egregious result of that.  The copy of the episode that I have has the view screen appearing much closer to black than that A/B effects video.

[image]

We know that the original was black because on the TNG series DVDs there is a roundtable with four men who did visual effects on all the TV series.  This group includes Howard Anderson, who produced the space effects for the original Star Trek series.  He describes how the moving star fields were achieved in the days of no computer graphics: black paint on white cards, shot, printed, reduced and then shot frame by frame while zooming, and then they used the negative of the result.

Comment: also, flat black is boring for the human eye to process, and really looks "fake" even when it's a real astronomical photo.  That's why Sci-Fi artists never use total black for space.

Comment: or indeed grey for shadows. Shadows always reflect colour from the objects near to them so a shadow under an apple would be hinted with green or red. We don't use full white either as it bleaches on screen, particularly text.